# Search multiline error log for error code and then some of it's parameters on Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

What command would give me the output I need for each instance of an error code in a very large log file? The file has records marked by a begin and end with number of characters. Such as:

```
SR 120
1414760452  0   1   Fri Oct 31 13:00:52 2014    2218714 4
    GROVEMR2    scn
../SrxParamIF.m     284

New Exam Started

EN 120
```

The 5th field is the error code, 2218714 in previous example.

I thought of just grep'ing for the error code and outputting -A lines afterwards; then picking what I needed from that rather than parsing the entire file. That seems easy but my grep/awk/sed usage isn't to that level.

ONLY when error 2274021 is encountered as in the following example I'd like some output as shown.

Show me output such as:       egrep ‘Coil:|Connector:|Channels faulted:| First channel:’ ERRORLOG|less

Part of input file of interest:

```
Mon Nov 24 13:43:37 2014        2274021 1
        AWHMRGE3T       NSP
SCP:RfHubCanHWO::RfBias         4101
^MException Class: Unknown   Severity: Unknown
Function: RF: RF Bias
PSD: VIBRANT   Coil: Breast SMI   Scan: 1106/14
Coil Fault - Short Circuit
A multicoil bias fault was detected.
.
Connector: Port 1 (P1)
Channels faulted: 0x200
First channel: 10 of 32, counting from 1
Fault value: -2499 mV, Channel: 10->
```

Output:

```
Coil: Breast SMI
Connector: Port 1 (P1)
Channels faulted: 0x200
First channel: 10 of 32, counting from 1
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: You could use logstash with the multiline filter and grok to extract the field

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (with the convenient adaptations)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
$/="\nEN ";                               # register separated by "\nEN "
my $error=2274021;                        # the error!
while(<>){                                # for all registers
  next unless /\b$error\b/;                   # ignore unless error
  for my $line ( split(/\n/,$_)){
     print "$line\n" if ($line =~ /Coil:|Connector:|Channels faulted:|First channel:/);
  }
  print "====\n"
}
```

Is this what you need?